# Java message sender brakes the rest of program

Tags: java, spam

Ok, so as the title said i got this small tool that helps me and i wanted to add "sort of message spammer" but when it starts i can't stop it.

Here's the code:

```
SpamScriptToggleButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
            if (ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                i = 3;
            } else if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                i = 1;
            }
        while(i > 2) {
            robot.delay(40);
            type("Message "+i+" !");
            i++;
            }
        }
    });
```

My question is how i can make it stop, clicking the ToggleButton doesn't help, and please keep in mind that i need to count those messages.

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listener is called on the Event Dispatch Thread https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html While this is busy it can't do anything else like handle your cancel button, or update the screen.

Any non trivial task to be run in a thread of it's own.